# XSLT - Group and Sum in multiple childnode

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

Trying to make an XSLT transformation of a BalanceList xml.

The Input is structured with Child elements to drill down the detail from Product -> Batch -> Locations (with StockResevationKey).

The Output needs to be flattend with repeating product elements grouped and summed by BatchId and StockResevationKey (if exists)

So the "unique product Quantity" would be identified by:
**ExtProductId + BatchId + StockResevationKey** (Both BatchId and StockResevationKey is'nt always present on all products).

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BalanceList>
    <TransactionId>20642</TransactionId>
    <Products>
        <Product>
            <Quantity>100.000</Quantity>     
            <ProductText>Item_1</ProductText>
            <ExtProductId>0320366</ExtProductId>
            <ExtId/>
            <Batches>
                <Batch>
                    <Quantity>80.000</Quantity>       
                    <BatchId>1234</BatchId>
                    <ProductLocations>
                        <ProductLocation>
                            <ExtLocationId>100362-01-01</ExtLocationId>
                            <Quantity>20.000</Quantity>                         
                            <StockReservationKey>1111</StockReservationKey>
                        </ProductLocation>
                        <ProductLocation>
                            <ExtLocationId>100359-01-01</ExtLocationId>
                            <Quantity>40.000</Quantity>
                            <StockReservationKey>1111</StockReservationKey>
                        </ProductLocation>
                        <ProductLocation>
                            <ExtLocationId>100368-01-01</ExtLocationId>
                            <Quantity>20.000</Quantity>
                            <StockReservationKey>2222</StockReservationKey>
                        </ProductLocation>
                    </ProductLocations>
                </Batch>
                <Batch>
                    <Quantity>20.000</Quantity>
                    <BatchId>2345</BatchId>
                    <ProductLocations>
                        <ProductLocation>
                            <ExtLocationId>100897-01-01</ExtLocationId>
                            <Quantity>10.000</Quantity>
                            <StockReservationKey>2222</StockReservationKey>
                        </ProductLocation>
                        <ProductLocation>
                            <ExtLocationId>104567-01-01</ExtLocationId>
                            <Quantity>10.000</Quantity>
                            <StockReservationKey />
                        </ProductLocation>
                    </ProductLocations>
                </Batch>
            </Batches>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Quantity>200.000</Quantity>
            <ProductText>Item_2</ProductText>
            <ExtProductId>0358523</ExtProductId>
            <ExtId/>
            <Batches>
                <Batch>
                    <Quantity>100.000</Quantity>
                    <BatchId>222</BatchId>
                    <ProductLocations>
                        <ProductLocation>
                            <ExtLocationId>100365-01-01</ExtLocationId>
                            <Quantity>100.000</Quantity>
                            <StockReservationKey/>
                        </ProductLocation>
                    </ProductLocations>
                </Batch>
                <Batch>
                    <Quantity>100.000</Quantity>
                    <BatchId>333</BatchId>
                    <ProductLocations>
                        <ProductLocation>
                            <ExtLocationId>100399-01-01</ExtLocationId>
                            <Quantity>100.000</Quantity>
                            <StockReservationKey/>
                        </ProductLocation>
                    </ProductLocations>
                </Batch>
            </Batches>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</BalanceList>
```

Wanted Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BalanceList>
    <TransactionId>20642</TransactionId>
    <Product>
        <ProductText>Item_1</ProductText>
        <ExtProductId>0320366</ExtProductId>  --(Concat key = 0320366+1234+1111)
        <Quantity>60.000</Quantity>
        <BatchId>1234</BatchId>
        <StockReservationKey>1111</StockReservationKey>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductText>Item_1</ProductText>
        <ExtProductId>0320366</ExtProductId>  --(Concat key = 0320366+1234+2222)
        <Quantity>20.000</Quantity>
        <BatchId>1234</BatchId>
        <StockReservationKey>2222</StockReservationKey>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductText>Item_1</ProductText>
        <ExtProductId>0320366</ExtProductId>   --(Concat key = 0320366+2345+2222)
        <Quantity>10.000</Quantity>
        <BatchId>2345</BatchId>
        <StockReservationKey>2222</StockReservationKey>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductText>Item_1</ProductText>
        <ExtProductId>0320366</ExtProductId>   --(Concat key = 0320366+2345)
        <Quantity>10.000</Quantity>
        <BatchId>2345</BatchId>
        <StockReservationKey/>
    </Product>
    
    <Product>
        <ProductText>Item_2</ProductText>
        <ExtProductId>0358523</ExtProductId>   --(Concat key = 0358523+222)
        <Quantity>100.000</Quantity>
        <BatchId>222</BatchId>
        <StockReservationKey/>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductText>Item_2</ProductText>
        <ExtProductId>0358523</ExtProductId>   --(Concat key = 0358523+333)
        <Quantity>100.000</Quantity>
        <BatchId>333</BatchId>
        <StockReservationKey/>
    </Product>
    
    <Product>
        <ProductText>Item_3</ProductText>
        <ExtProductId>0358500</ExtProductId>   --(Concat key = 0358500)
        <Quantity>50.000</Quantity>
        <BatchId/>
        <StockReservationKey/>
    </Product>
</BalanceList>
```

So fare I got to this point, but can't figure out the last steps to make the Sum correct and next product to show.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="ProductGroup" match="BalanceList/Products/Product" use="ExtProductId"/>
    <xsl:key name="ProductBatchGroup" match="BalanceList/Products/Product/Batches/Batch" use="BatchId"/>
    <xsl:key name="ProductLocationGroup" match="BalanceList/Products/Product/Batches/Batch/ProductLocations/ProductLocation" use="StockReservationKey"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <BalanceList>
            <Products>
                <xsl:for-each select="BalanceList/Products/Product[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ProductGroup', ExtProductId)[1])]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Batches/Batch[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ProductBatchGroup', BatchId)[1])]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="ProductLocations/ProductLocation[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ProductLocationGroup', StockReservationKey)[1])]">
                        <xsl:variable name="Reservation-group" select="ProductLocations/ProductLocation[StockReservationKey = current()/StockReservationKey]"/>
                            <Product>
                                <ProductText>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../../../ProductText"/>
                                </ProductText>
                                <ExtProductId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../../../ExtProductId"/>
                                </ExtProductId>
                                <BatchId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../BatchId"/>
                                </BatchId>
                                <StockReservationKey>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="StockReservationKey"/>
                                </StockReservationKey>
                                <Quantity>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(Quantity)"/>
                                </Quantity>
                            </Product>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Products>
        </BalanceList>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where does `Item_3` in your output come from?

Comment: ahh Sorry - missing the "Item_3" in the Input sample.. IAdded it to the Output to show that BatchId could be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, the following stylesheet does what you want:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="ProductLocation" use="concat(ancestor::Product/ExtProductId, '|', ancestor::Batch/BatchId, '|', StockReservationKey)"/>

<xsl:template match="/BalanceList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="TransactionId"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Products/Product/Batches/Batch/ProductLocations/ProductLocation[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', concat(ancestor::Product/ExtProductId, '|', ancestor::Batch/BatchId, '|', StockReservationKey))[1])]">
            <Product>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Product/ProductText"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Product/ExtProductId"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Batch/BatchId"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="StockReservationKey"/>
                <Quantity>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k1', concat(ancestor::Product/ExtProductId, '|', ancestor::Batch/BatchId, '|', StockReservationKey))/Quantity)"/>
                </Quantity>
            </Product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>                    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```